# JavaScript Como actualizo esta tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, api

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto. Estoy usando la api de API-Football.
Estoy usando un llamado a la api cada 1 minuto, donde `live();` es el la funcion que contiene el Fetch a la API.

```
setInterval(() => {
    live();
}, 60000);
```

**En mi HTML tengo una tabla** la cual necesito que cambie los datos que contiene por cada llamado a la API, es decir, cada 1 minuto:

**La tabla**

```
<tbody id="tBody"></tbody>
```

**Javascript**

```
const tableBody = document.querySelector("#tBody");


 liveMatches.fixtures.forEach(element => {
        let appendTr = document.createElement("tr");
        appendTr.classList.add("liveMatchTr");
        appendTr.innerHTML = `<td> ${element.homeTeam.team_name} vs ${element.awayTeam.team_name}  </td>`
        tableBody.appendChild(appendTr);
    });
```

**El problema radica en que cada llamado a la API me "pushea" la tabla, entonces cada 1 minuto se va agrandando la tabla.**
Lo que necesito es que la Tabla se vacíe, y cada minuto que pasa se "actualice"

Comment: `tableBody.innerHTML = "";`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer para vaciar la tabla o cualquier elemento html es lo siguiente:

```
while (tableBody.firstChild){
    tableBody.removeChild(tableBody.firstChild);
}
```